# Spread waiting time among connection requests and performance issues

Tags: performance, netty

I developed a server for a custom protocol based on tcp/ip-stack with Netty. Writing this was a pleasure.

Right now I am testing performance. I wrote a test-application on netty that simply connects lots (20.000+) of "clients" to the server (for-loop with Thread.wait(1) after each bootstrap-connect). As soon as a client-channel is connected it sends a login-request to the server, that checks the account and sends a login-response.

The overall performance seems to be quite OK. All clients are logged in below 60s. But what's not so good is the spread waiting time per connections. I have extremely fast logins and extremely slow logins. Variing from 9ms to 40.000ms spread over the whole test-time. Is it somehow possible to share waiting time among the requesting channels (Fifo)?

I measured a lot of significant timestamps and found a strange phenomenon. I have a lot of connections where the server's timestamp of "channel-connected" is way after the client's timestamp (up to 19 seconds). I also do have the "normal" case, where they match and just the time between client-sending and server-reception is several seconds. And there are cases of everything in between those two cases. How can it be, that client and server "channel-connected" are so much time away from each other?

What is for sure is, that the client immediatly receives the server's login-response after it has been send.

Tuning:
I think I read most of the performance-articles around here. I am using the OrderMemoryAwareThreadPool with 200 Threads on a 4CPU-Hyper-Threading-i7 for the incoming connections and also do start the server-application with the known aggressive-options. I also completely tweaked my Win7-TCP-Stack.
The server runs very smooth on my machine. CPU-usage and memory consumption is ca. at 50% from what could be used.

Too much information:
I also started 2 of my test-apps from 2 seperate machines "attacking" the server in parallel with 15.000 connections each. There I had about 800 connections that got a timeout from the server. Any comments here?

Best regards and cheers to Netty,
Martin

Comment: The article http://blog.xebia.fr/2011/11/09/java-nio-et-framework-web-haute-performance/ states 9k requests per second. By now I am at about 350 requests per second. I guess I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 2):

Netty has a dedicated boss thread that accepts an incoming connection.  If the boss thread accepts a new connection, it forwards the connection to a worker thread.  The latency between the acceptance and the actual socket read might be larger than expected under load because of this.  Although we are looking into different ways to improve the situation, meanwhile, you might want to increase the number of worker threads so that a worker thread handles less number of connections.

If you think it's performing way worse than non-Netty application, please feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues) with reproducing test case.  We will try to reproduce and fix the problem.

Comment: To raise the number of worker threads I would have to change the thread-pool's number of threads, right? That I've tested already with slightly negative performance compared to my current number of 200 threads.
Are there any other hints? Is the Thread.wait(1) OK in my test-client or is that simply producing way too much load? Do other users have experiences with a similar performance behaviour? I'm simply searching for bottlenecks.

Comment: You must use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and specify an integer parameter when you construct a `ChannelFactory`.

Comment: Trustin, does it mean that there are 3 threads handling a request.. (1) boss thread recieves request passes to (2) IO worker thread. The request is then passed to handlers which may use (3) another thread (from thread pool which is set in pipeline) ?

Comment: The point I missed at that time was the "execution handler". My application was already connected to a database and at my performance-tests the worker-threads were blocked while waiting for db to return.
The Ordered-Thread-Pool I wrote about was given to the server-bootstrap as pool for worker threads because I had no clue about the "execution handler"-model.
Maybe Netty could add a standard example, how to connect Netty to a database to promote this so important feature?